# Get bit value from database and show in CheckBox in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

How do I to get a bit value from a database table and show its value in a  checkbox (e.g if value is TRUE then it's checked, otherwise checkbox is unchecked) in a GridView? Also, how do I get the checkbox value and insert it into a database table which has a "bit" datatype column?

Here is my table [image](http://hostthenpost.org/uploads/d18c993aadfe7a54fdb9e9b626cbde29.png)

And here is my GridView [image](http://hostthenpost.org/uploads/d0c8e23d588fffb710d34a961f313069.png)

Here is my .CS code:

```
public void lbinssert(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    sql.InsertParameters["ColumnName"].DefaultValue =
        ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtColName")).Text;

    sql.InsertParameters["Dtype"].DefaultValue =
        ((DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownList2")).Text;

    sql.InsertParameters["id"].DefaultValue =
        ((DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownList2")).Text;

    sql.InsertParameters["null"].DefaultValue =
        ((CheckBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("nulll")).Text;

    sql.InsertParameters["primary"].DefaultValue = 
        ((CheckBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("primary")).Text;

    sql.Insert();
}
```

Here is my .aspx code:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column_Name" SortExpression="Column_Name">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Column_Name")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Text="*" ID="colname" ControlToValidate="txtName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Column Name is Required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Column_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtColName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="INSERT" Text="*" ID="insertcolname" ControlToValidate="txtColName"runat="server" ErrorMessage="Column Name is Required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data_Type" SortExpression="Data_Type">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Data_Type") %>'>
                    <asp:ListItem>Select Datatype</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>int</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Float</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Varchar(50)</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Varchar(100)</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>double</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="datatype" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1"
                    runat="server" ErrorMessage="Data Type is Required" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="Select Datatype">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Data_Type") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>Select Datatype</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>int</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Float</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Varchar(50)</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Varchar(100)</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>double</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="INSERT" Text="*"  ID="datatype" ControlToValidate="DropDownList2"
                    runat="server" ErrorMessage="Data Type is Required" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="Select Datatype">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Allow_Null_" SortExpression="Allow_Null_">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Allow_Null_").ToString().Equals("1") %>'/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Allow_Null_").ToString().Equals("1") %>' enabled="false" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="nulll" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Primary_Key_" SortExpression="Primary_Key_">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Primary_Key_").ToString().Equals("1") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" 
                    Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Primary_Key_").ToString().Equals("1") %>' Enabled="false" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="primary" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ValidationGroup="INSERT" OnClick="lbinssert" ID="lblInsert" runat="server">Insert</asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate> 
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
</asp:GridView>

<asp:ValidationSummary ValidationGroup="INSERT" ID="ValidationSummary1" ForeColor="Red"
    runat="server" Height="54px" style="margin-left: 140px" />

<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary2" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" 
    style="margin-left: 161px" />

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sql" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:db_compilerConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Column_Name], [Data_Type], [Allow_Null_], [Primary_Key_], [Date] FROM [tbl_field]"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE * FROM [tbl_field] WHERE [Field_id]=@field" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tbl_field] ([Column_Name],[Data_Type],[Database_id],[Allow_Null_],[Primary_Key_])Values (@ColumnName,@Dtype,@id,@null,@primary)"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tbl_field] SET [Column_Name]=@ColumnName,[Data_Type]=@Dtype,[Database_id]=@id,[Allow_Null_]=@null,[Primary_Key_]=@primary">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="field" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ColumnName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Dtype" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="null" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="primary" Type="Boolean" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ColumnName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Dtype" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="null" Type="Boolean"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="primary" Type="Boolean" /> 
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The value is inserted into the database, but "Allow_Null_" and "Primary_Key_" are showing "NULL". Please tell me how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Instead of this line `sql.InsertParameters["null"].DefaultValue =
((CheckBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("nulll")).Text;`, you can use `checked` property like  this - `sql.InsertParameters["use_properColumn"].DefaultValue =
((CheckBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("nulll")).Checked;`

Comment: But i define string which name is "null" in <InsertParamaeters> ,"null" is nothing just string name,and string name can be anything,I think it's not issue

Comment: Here is define 
 <asp:Parameter Name="null" Type="Boolean" />
       


     </InsertParameters>

Comment: @Krishnraj Values comes from "insertparameters"

Comment: Okay, Did you tried by adding this line - `sql.InsertParameters["null"].DefaultValue = ((CheckBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("nulll")).Checked;` ? Debug the application and see what you get.

Comment: I try this ,values inserted no error come but issue is "Allow_Null_" and "Primary_Key_" columns show "NULL"

Comment: @Krishnraj red line error come when i apply ".Checked" ,here is error show blow "Cannot implicity convert type "bool" to string "

Comment: Okay then try this - `sql.InsertParameters["null"].DefaultValue = ((CheckBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("nulll")).Checked == true ? "true":"false";`. This should work.

Comment: How come this relates to sql-server. please use tags properly.

Comment: @Krishnaraj Thanks ,half work done,now database table both columns contain values in form of "0" and "1" ,but gridview output remain same,both column checkbox untick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this line -

```
sql.InsertParameters["null"].DefaultValue =
  ((CheckBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("nulll")).Checked == true ? "true":"false";

sql.InsertParameters["primary"].DefaultValue = 
   ((CheckBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("primary")).Checked == true ? "true":"false";
```

And as per your comment that - in gridview output remain same,both column checkbox untick.

Try below code

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
            Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Allow_Null_")) %>' enabled="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
```

No need of this code-

```
Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Allow_Null_").ToString().Equals("1") %>'
```

Comment: soory to say but error come when i try this 'Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Allow_Null_") %>' enabled="false" />" ',Here is error  Specified cast is not valid.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Allow_Null_")%>' enabled="false" />

Comment: @Saira: Oh my fault....Please check my updated answer. You need to use `Convert.ToBoolean` method for that.

Comment: again error come,,,here is error "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.this line have error " <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Allow_Null_"))%>' enabled="false" />"

Comment: @KrishnaRaj thanks now it's working,when i truncate table from the database and now i insert new values now working fine,issue comes due to NULL values in table,Thnakss awesomeee